# Finding rational coefficients of a cubic polynomial that fits 4 data points that have been floored to an integer

Tags: polynomials, interpolation, cubics, data-analysis, lagrange-interpolation

I have 4 data points:

- (204, 5422892)
- (205, 5722486)
- (207, 6343357)
- (213, 8386502)

I have information that these data points were generated with a cubic polynomial

$y = ax ^ 3 + bx ^ 2 + cx + d$

with $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ being rational (but not necessarily integral) coefficients, and with the resulting $y$ values being floats that were floored to an integer (the $x$ values are known to be true integers, not floored floats). I also have information that the coefficients are relatively "nice", "simple", or "short" numbers with only a few digits like $50$ or $1/2$ rather than anything that is a long string of many digits.

I need to determine what those coefficients are. I tried submitting the query

"`find cubic polynomial that fits (204, 5422892), (205, 5722486), (207, 6343357), (213, 8386502)`"

to Wolfram Alpha, but Wolfram Alpha gives me the answer

$(589/36) x ^ 3 - (116363/18) x ^ 2 + (10691263/12) x - 46197659$

which has coefficients that are rational but are not "nice" (in the sense used above). I think the difficulty is that Wolfram Alpha is using Lagrange interpolation to try to find a cubic polynomial that is an absolute exact fit to the given data points, but there is actually flooring to an integer being applied to the $y$ values.

So can anyone help me...

(1) find the coefficients for this specific case of the 4 data points given above?

(2) show me how to, in general, given any 4 data points that are known to be generated with a cubic polynomial with rational coefficients with the $y$ values then floored to an integer, find those coefficients? (I am aware of Lagrange interpolation, but I think that is what Wolfram Alpha is doing above and is what is giving wrong results due to not being able to take into account flooring.)

Comment: What do you want? You have the linear system in the unknowns $a,b,c,d$
$$x_i^3a+x_i^2b+x_ic+1\cdot d=y_i;\space i=1,2,3,4$$ which if compatible determines a unique solution $(a,b,c,d)$. All artificial thing you add makes a full change.

Comment: This is an interesting question. What makes you sure the coefficients are positive, though? The various approximate $y$ values you have define ranges of possible "true" $y$ values. It's easy enough to scan this parameter space and solve for $a,b,c,d$. I've tried this, but never got all of the coefficients to be positive.

Comment: @Chris Lewis: Hmm, okay, I see the problem. The context is that I am trying to reverse-engineer the behavior of some software. Related parts of the software that I have been able to reverse-engineer all use cubic polynomials with positive rational "nice" (in the sense given above) coefficients and then apply flooring, so I assumed it was true of this part as well, but it looks like at least the "positive" part of that pattern is being broken. I'll edit out positive in the original question.